# How change shortcut path without update your icon?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, shortcut-file

I have the following code that changes path of one shortcut. Happens that when path is changed, the icon also is updated to icon of new application.

How change path wihout update icon of shortcut?

```
uses
 ActiveX,
 ComObj, 
 ShlObj;
 
 ...

function GetDesktopFolder: string;
var
  buf: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  pidList: PItemIDList;
begin
  Result := '';
  SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(Application.Handle, CSIDL_DESKTOP, pidList);
  if (pidList <> nil) then
    if (SHGetPathFromIDList(pidList, buf)) then
      Result := buf;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyObject: IUnknown;
  MySLink: IShellLink;
  MyPFile: IPersistFile;
  LnkPath, sExePath, sParams: string;
begin
  sParams := '';
  sExePath := 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe';
  LnkPath := GetDesktopFolder + '\Target.lnk';
  MyObject := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink);
  MySLink := MyObject as IShellLink;
  MyPFile := MyObject as IPersistFile;

  with MySLink do
  begin
    SetDescription('');
    SetPath(PWideChar(sExePath));
    SetArguments(PWideChar(sParams));
    SetWorkingDirectory(PWideChar(ExtractFilePath(sExePath)));
    SetIconLocation(PWideChar(''), 0);
  end;

  MyPFile.Save(PWChar(WideString(LnkPath)), False);
  SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATH, PWideChar(LnkPath), nil);
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent the icon from being updated.

What you can do is retrieve the current icon via `IShellLink.GetIconLocation()` before setting the new path, and then you can restore the icon afterwards, eg:

```pascal
function GetDesktopFolder(Wnd: HWND = 0): string;
var
  buf: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  if Wnd = 0 then Wnd := Application.Handle;
  if Succeeded(SHGetFolderPath(Wnd, CSIDL_DESKTOP, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, buf)) then
    Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(buf)
  else
    Result := '';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MySLink: IShellLink;
  MyPFile: IPersistFile;
  sLnkPath, sExePath, sParams: string;
  szIconPath: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  iIconIndex: Integer;
  bHasIcon: Boolean;
begin
  sParams := '';
  sExePath := 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe';
  sLnkPath := GetDesktopFolder(Handle) + 'Target.lnk';

  MySLink := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink) as IShellLink;
  MyPFile := MySLink as IPersistFile;

  if Succeeded(MyPFile.Load(PChar(sLnkPath), STGM_READ)) then
  begin
    MySLink.Resolve(Handle, 0); 
    bHasIcon := Succeeded(MySLink.GetIconLocation(szIconPath, Length(szIconPath), @iIconIndex));
  end;

  with MySLink do
  begin
    SetDescription(PChar(''));
    SetPath(PChar(sExePath));
    SetArguments(PChar(sParams));
    SetWorkingDirectory(PChar(ExtractFilePath(sExePath)));
    if bHasIcon then
      SetIconLocation(szIconPath, iIconIndex)
    else
      SetIconLocation(PChar(''), 0);
  end;

  MyPFile.Save(PChar(sLnkPath), False);
  SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATH, PChar(sLnkPath), nil);
end;
```

Comment: Only one curiosity: Is possible change path and working directory of a way that not can be seen by **right button** > **properties** of shortcut? Ex: suppose that i want change path and working directory of Mozilla Firefox to Google Chrome, after it, [here](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot_1_54.png) is possible see the original data before update like if nothing had be changed?

Comment: Of course not. Why would you ever want that?

Comment: By default Shortcut don't have any icon assigned to them. So what windows does in such scenario is it retrieves the icon from the target file if possible and use it as shortcut icon. That is why changing shortcut target also changes the shortcut icon. But if you assign an icon to the shortcut then that icon will be shown regardless of what shortcut target is.